# Kafka consumer not reading messages after restart. I am using weiboad / kafka-php

Tags: apache-kafka

Following is my Consumer and Producer Script :
**Consumer Script**

```
$config = ConsumerConfig::getInstance();
$config->setMetadataRefreshIntervalMs(10000);
$config->setMetadataBrokerList('localhost:9092');
$config->setGroupId('test');
$config->setBrokerVersion('1.1.1');
$config->setTopics(['Request']);
$config->setOffsetReset('earliest');
$consumer = new Consumer();
$consumer->setLogger($logger);
$consumer->start(function($topic, $part, $message) {
var_dump($message);
});
```

**Producer Script**

```
$config = ProducerConfig::getInstance();
$config->setMetadataRefreshIntervalMs(10000);
$config->setMetadataBrokerList('localhost:9092');
$config->setBrokerVersion('1.1.1');
$config->setRequiredAck(1);
$config->setIsAsyn(false);
$config->setProduceInterval(500);
$producer = new \Kafka\Producer(
function() {
return [
[
'topic' => 'Request',
'value' => 'My Test Data',
],
];
}
);
$producer->success(function($result) {
var_dump($result);
});
$producer->error(function($errorCode) {
var_dump($errorCode);
});
$producer->send(true);
```

It is working fine. When consumer is running and producer is publishing data, consumer is able to read it. But once i stop consumer and then publish data and then start consumer, Consumer does not read that data. What am i doing wrong? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` it doesn't mean that the consumer will always read events from the very beginning. The setting is used to define a consumer behavior when there is no committed offset. Alternatively, it can be configured as `latest` or `none`.

`enable.auto.commit` defaults to `true` which means that Kafka consumer will periodically commit its current offset.

Also, you have a configured consumer group id which means that your app will just carry on consuming where it finished after restart.

If you always want to process messages from the very beginning you can set `enable.auto.commit=false` or remove group id.

Please, see [consumer configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#ak-consumer-configuration)

> The two main settings affecting offset management are whether
>   auto-commit is enabled and the offset reset policy. First, if you set
>   enable.auto.commit (which is the default), then the consumer will
>   automatically commit offsets periodically at the interval set by
>   auto.commit.interval.ms. The default is 5 seconds.
>
> Second, use auto.offset.reset to define the behavior of the consumer
>   when there is no committed position (which would be the case when the
>   group is first initialized) or when an offset is out of range. You can
>   choose either to reset the position to the “earliest” offset or the
>   “latest” offset (the default). You can also select “none” if you would
>   rather set the initial offset yourself and you are willing to handle
>   out of range errors manually.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I dont want to read messages from beginning, instead, i want to read messages from where consumer stopped last time. Like i said, once i stop cosumer and producer publish some data to topic and then i again start consumer, it is not reading that data. I want my consumer to read that data from where it last left.